Fermat's little theorem in $F_p(x,y)$
I'm currently starting to study finite fields and I'm wondering if Fermat's little theorem always apply. We know that $a^p \equiv a$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, but f.e. is it true that $x^p \equiv x$ in $\mathbb{F}_p(x,y)$ ? Does it even make sense to formulate it like that, as $x$ is a variable...

Remember that polynomials are formal expressions, so $x^p$ and $x$ can't be the same polynomial. Also, the polynomial $T^p-T$ can have at most $p$ roots in the field $\mathbb{F_p}(x,y)$, and since the elements of $\mathbb{F_p}$ are already $p$ roots, it can't have any other roots.

what do you mean exactly by "formal expressions" ?

I mean that two polynomials $\sum\limits_{i=0}^m a_ix^i$ and $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n b_ix^i$ are equal if and only if all of their coefficients are equal, not if they are equal as functions. So $x^p$ and $x$ are surely not the same polynomial: the coefficient of $x^p$ in one of the polynomials is $1$, in the other one it is $0$.
